# Wrap collections radio buttons in div in Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have this element in Simple Form for RoR:

```
<%= f.input "questions#{q.id}", label: q.label, collection: q.answers, as: :radio_buttons, value_method: :id, wrapper_html: { class: "question" } %>
```

I have to wrap my collection buttons in  with my custom class

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= f.input "questions#{q.id}", label: q.label, collection: q.answers, as: :radio_buttons, value_method: :id, collection_wrapper_class: "question" %>
```